# 2D isometric engine - Math problems - Cube selection - diamond shape map

Tags: c++, math, coordinates, isometric

I calculate my coordinates when i create a layer with a `std::vector`, filled with `cube` objects(wich is a class of mine):

```
for(int J = 0; J < mapSize; J++)
{
    for(int I = 0; I < mapSize; I++)
    {
        x = (J - I) * (cubeSize/2);
        y = (J + I) * (cubeSize/4);

        c = new cube(cubeSize, x, y, z, I, J);
        cs.push_back(*c);
    }
}
```

I wanna do this : `cs[getCubeByID(mouseX, mouseY)].setTexture(...);`

*Example of use: The cube in `I-J [0, 0]` have the `number 0` in the cubes array. if i `click on 0,0` i got this number.*

EDIT:
We gave me the formula to get a J or a I with a pair of x,y in the comments, thanks a lot. **I only need to convert this pair of I-J to the entry number of my array like the example i gave.**

I tried : `int entry = (J - 1) * size + (I - 1);` and the selected cube is not so far from the one i want but still not the right formula. Modular arithmetic can fix my problem but i don't understand how it's working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you want to convert an `x` and `y` pair back into `I` and `J`, `(2 * x + 4 * y) / (2 * cubeSize) = J`. Then it's simple to calculate `I` too.

Comment: I have my cursor coordinates(x,y), and i want to convert them in isometric coordinates(something like 0, 1 for example) if my click is on the map. Then, i want to convert (I,J) in the numero of my cube in the std::vector<cubes> (named  cs here)

Sorry for broken english, it was hard for me to explain all of this.

I tried your calculs, it didn't work, i don't get isometric coordinates.

Comment: Have you took a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art ?

Comment: I don't use tiles, but 4 points of vertex for the 6 sides of my cubes.

Comment: All I did was reverse the equation you had in the beginning. If that's not what you intended, I don't know what to calculate.

Comment: I don't want to reverse the equation, i want to calculate for an x and y, in wich cube they are(the I-J coordinates)

Comment: And how exactly do you take care of the z parts of your cubes coordinates?

Comment: When i display my cubes or i do getY() -> y - (z * (cubeSize/2)). Thanks for free downvote. I spent days on this problem... and the whole day to clarify my post. Sorry to no be english fluent....

Comment: Once you have transformed the coordinate of the vertex of the cube into screen coordinates I and J, you can store them for each face and find out for every position of the mouse what face is.

Comment: Each cube is associated with the pair (x,y). Are these the *minimum* x and y of the cube face, or the *maximum*, or the *center*, or what?

Comment: It's same as a classic 2D isometric  tile system. It's the start of the bouding box. (sorry if i'm not clear >_<). Then, i use the classic isometric formula to rotate all of this and calculate each points. So there is no I,J for the points.

Comment: I edited the whole post, i think i have now more clear ideas about what i want. I deleted all not needed informations.

Comment: So the question basically is “how to write a ray caster”? Such questions are a bit broad, and are generally considered off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: A ray what ??? I'm sorry, i don't know why i'm off-topic. I just want to select a cube with a left click, and for that i need formulas wich i can't find by myself.

Comment: I took a look on wikipedia, it's like it's a 3D technique, i'm using 2D here. I just fake the 3D using vertex, but it's still 2D.

Comment: @Madz Depends. If a few cubes overlap, do you want to get the cube which is “on top” of the others?

Comment: @roeland I'll do something like this with all those formulas : `maps[currentMapID].layers()[currentLayerID].cubes()[getCubeByID(cursorX, cursorY)].setTexture(numTexture);` currentLayerID will always be the layer at the top of all layers.

Comment: So (1) you're absolutely sure that no 2 cubes in a layer will overlap in image space? Think about that for a while, what if you click in an area where 2 cubes overlap. And (2) just implement a simple for loop. There is no magic formula.

Comment: I'm sure, the formula to calcul coordinates give me the coordinates for the upper side of my cube, the upper sides don't overlap beetween each others. (I just fake 3D with vertex, but i still use 2D method). I'm sure if i got those 3 formulas it will work perfectly. PS: I can get the coordinates of the side of my cube i want.

Comment: I would add something : math are not magic, i know, but numbers in an algorythm are always related, so i know those formulas exist.

Comment: @roeland I did a wrong use of your reverse formula, this is working thanks. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

```
x = (J - I) * (cubeSize/2);
y = (J + I) * (cubeSize/4);
```

and you want to compute `I` and `J` (and therefore the index which is `I + J*mapSize`) from that, right? It's a linear system of two equations.

```
J - I = x * 2 / cubeSize
J + I = y * 4 / cubeSize

I = (y * 2 - x) / cubeSize
J = (y * 2 + x) / cubeSize
```

Comment: It's not so easy, he has an isometric like drawing of 3d cubes (he posted some pictures, many version of this question ago). Basically you have to click on hexagonal tiles.

Comment: @Bob__: It kind of would have helped to see that picture in the question… Thanks to your comment I found [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fv2u.png) from [revision 7](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33881027/7). Adapting my answer to that shouldn't be too hard. I guess though that I'll leave my answer as it stands now until the question gets edited in such a way that its requirements can be found without digging through the revision history. OP, feel free to comment if I miss that event. I'm currently seeing revision 19.

Comment: @MvG this is totally what i want, really thanks to you ! but the index (I + J * size;) don't work, what do you mean by map size ? in pixel ? in blocks ? It's only working for the tile 0, 0.

Comment: @Madz: The `mapSize` I wrote is the same you used as the upper limit in your inner loop, where you wrote `I < mapSize`. Incrementing `J`, the variable from the outer loop, by one is equivalent to taking `mapSize` steps in the inner loop, i.e. one full execution of the loop.

Comment: And for a reason i ignore, you resolved my other problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852194/sfml-c-sftexture-applied-in-a-wrong-way Maybe be math are really magic after all ha ha ha O_O